# combine AspNetWindowsAuthProvider and CredentialsAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack, windows-authentication

Is it possible to use the AspNetWindowsAuthProvider and fallback to the CredentialsAuthProvider if the current user is not logged in into a Windows domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like any other AuthProviders where you can register all the Authentication options you wish to allow, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new CustomUserSession(), //Use your own typed Custom UserSession type
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new AspNetWindowsAuthProvider(this) {
            AllowAllWindowsAuthUsers = true
        }, 
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
    }));
```

Users would still need to explicitly log in with their chosen Auth Option, i.e. to login with Windows Auth they would need to access `/auth/windowsauth` route whilst to login with Credentials Auth they would need to explicitly post their Username/Password, i.e:

```
<form action="/auth/credentials">
    <input type="text" name="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="Password" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Note: The `CredentialsAuthProvider` only allows access to users registered in the Auth Providers, e.g. users who've registered with the RegistrationService (i.e `/register`), it's not linked to WindowsAuth.

Comment: Thanks, but i want a fallback mechanism, first try windows authentication, if failed redirect to the CredentialsAuthProvider. Is that possible?

Comment: @Marco If it fails when they go to `/auth/windowsauth` it will redirect back to login page with additional hashparam `#f=Windows+Auth+Failed` on the url. You could use JS onload to detect this and show them the credentials Username/Password form.